# Mobile web application performance depending on the scale size

Tags: cordova, mobile, view, web

I have a question about mobile applications.

I am designing an app for mobile platform using PhoneGap.

So i wonder, is it best to design an app lets say for `480x320` and scale it up for big devices using `initial-scale`, or i can design for iPhone resolution `960x640` and just scale the app down?

Are mobile browsers smart enough to downsample pixels, that are not displayed, or do they still take up processing/rendering time? And will the `480x320` one run faster?

Thanks!